# “disparate” as a noun vs the gerund-participial clause “waiting outside” as modifier of the head

Tags: sentence-construction

> In legal contexts, **“disparate”** as **a noun** is often associated with the concept of disparate impact or treatment.

> The noun phrase "two people waiting outside" has “people” as head with **the gerund-participial clause “waiting outside”** as **modifier of the head**.

Is the grammatical construction of "**the gerund-participial clause “waiting outside”** as **modifier of the head**" similar to that of "**the gerund-participial clause “waiting outside”** as **modifier of the head**"?

Comment: I think your last paragraph was meant to ask what I have answered.

Comment: If so, please edit it.

Comment: I've never run into **disparate** used as a noun in a legal document.

Comment: Please write out those sentences in full so we don't have to do it, in our heads. disparate is just an adjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

> "**disparate**” as **a noun**

the preposition phrase acts as an adjective and modifies ***disparate***.   ***a noun*** is the object of the preposition *as*.

In

> **the gerund-participial clause “waiting outside**” as **modifier of the head**.

the same relation applies.

As for your last paragraph,  I believe you are asking about the 2 quoted noun phrases in the following description.

> **disparate** as **a noun**

is the subject of your first sentence, but

> **the gerund-participial clause waiting outside** as **modifier of the head**

is the object of preposition *with*, of your second sentence.